# Copy array into part of another array in NumPy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'd like to copy smaller array A into bigger array B, like so: 
[image: copy array into part of another array]
The obvious way to do this is to calculate which part of A would fit into B and copy only this part to the also precalculated part of the destination array B. This is a tedious and error-prone task, especially in higher dimesions. Is there an easier (i.e. without having to calculate all the indices) way to achive this?

A word of clarification - normally one would have to:

in X axis: calculate how many elements of A fit in B part, subtract this from A size, recalculate starting and ending point (indices) in B where they fit, recalculate indices in A. Repeat in second dimension (possibly more). Insert looong slicing formula, which is in no way readable and then be sure not to miss anything in the process. This is what I mean by *tedious and error-prone*. It can be done, but is there a better way?

Comment: Besides `A` and `B` what are the givens? How is the region of overlap specified?

Comment: @unutbu basically everything needed is given (bounding boxes, sizes, indices where you want to put A in B). What I'm after is only simplifying the whole process, so there is less places to make errors while calculating all the indices. The overlap may be defined as *(x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end)*.

Comment: @unutbu ok, I might have said too much - not *all* indices are given, only the starting and ending point. Sorry for not being specific enough.

Comment: Why do you consider this to be a tedious and error-prone task? Calculating the start and end indices in each dimension for both A and B seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: @user2653663 see updated question.

Comment: you should probably ask algorithm questions like this on the computer science stack exchange site, this isn't a programming questions it's an algorithm related question

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite algorithm is what I'm trying to *avoid*. This is a NumPy capabilities question.

Comment: Unless you are thinking of some procedure which is not separable in each dimension (in which case you should explain yourself better), I think you are overlooking how simple a slicing and a looping is (which is just about as far as Python / NumPy can get you), when you describe your "tedious and error-prone" procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of NumPy array arithmetic to handle N dimensions the same as you would 1 dimension. Moreover, computing the slices for N dimension can be handled with 
calls to `map(slice, start_indices, end_indices)`, and once these slices are generated, the actual copying becomes a one-liner: `B[B_slices] = A[A_slices]`:

```
import numpy as np

def copy_from(A, B, A_start, B_start, B_end):
    """
    A_start is the index with respect to A of the upper left corner of the overlap
    B_start is the index with respect to B of the upper left corner of the overlap
    B_end is the index of with respect to B of the lower right corner of the overlap
    """
    A_start, B_start, B_end = map(np.asarray, [A_start, B_start, B_end])
    shape = B_end - B_start
    B_slices = tuple(map(slice, B_start, B_end + 1))
    A_slices = tuple(map(slice, A_start, A_start + shape + 1))
    B[B_slices] = A[A_slices]

A = np.zeros((21,15))
B = np.ones((16,15))
A_start = [11, 5]
B_start =  [6, 0]
B_end =  [15, 9]
copy_from(A, B, A_start, B_start, B_end)
print(B)
```

yields

```
[[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: You should change `list(map(...` to `tuple(map(...` or you'll get a `FutureWarning: Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated; use \`arr[tuple(seq)]\` instead of \`arr[seq]\`. In the future this will be interpreted as an array index, \`arr[np.array(seq)]\`, which will result either in an error or a different result.` with newer versions of NumPy like `1.15.2`.